# Why am I getting a NullPointerException in this project?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-tabs, tween

Now that this problem is over ill address the rest of it. Heres my working code:

```
package edu.wmich.lab4_jjohns1119;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.Animation;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

//Declare widget objects
Button btnAnimate;
ImageView imgTween;
Animation tweenAnimation;

//create view
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//Inflater
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);
//Button
     btnAnimate = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnAnimate);   
     //Image
     imgTween = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgTween);
     //Animation Resource
    tweenAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.tween1);
//Button listener for animation
btnAnimate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //animate image
        imgTween.startAnimation(tweenAnimation);
    }

});
//Return view
return rootView;
}
}
```

it launches, it navigates, but the animation does nothing. my guess is the order of the code is incorrect ad it is displaying the view before an animation. heres my tween1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
xmlns:android="http//schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="-45"
android:duration="400"
 />
```

Comment: Post your stack trace. Then we can see the line that is throwing the exception. Else we could be here for hours too.

Comment: pardon my ignorance but i cant seem to figure out how to get the stack trace. do you mean the logcat output?

Comment: @pfortyseven yes, the logcat output.

Comment: seems to be the line of code where i declare my button....but why?

Comment: Found it! 
The namespace in xml file is wrong. 
Add ":" after "http".

Comment: the problem was rootview instead of getview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using getView()?
Move all you assignments below rootView and do:

```
btnAnimate = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnAnimate);
```

For animation to work, change the namespace declaration to:

```
http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
```

(Note the colon after http is missing in your sample)

....

Comment: Thank you!!! no more crashing. now just to figure out why the animate button does nothing to the image....

Comment: which would be something i need to change in tween1.xml right?

Comment: you're welcome. Not sure about anim. maybe tween1.xml is missing something.

Comment: just posted it. @jose

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies with assigning your `tweenAnimation` field

```
Animation tweenAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.tween1);
```

`getActivity()` is null at this point in your fragments lifecycle (creation) and will cause `loadAnimation` to fail or return a null animation. Accessing this will then result in a NPE (if `loadAnimation` hasn't already thrown one)

Move assigning `tweenAnimation` to a point in the fragment's lifecycle where the activity will exist like `onCreate`

ex.

```
Animation tweenAnimation;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreat(savedInstanceState);
    tweenAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.tween1);
}
```

Comment: Nice observation. I missed that.

Comment: Please see my edit, theres still a problem somewhere

Comment: The Logcat would still help.

Comment: @KieronPapps you got it. just posted

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can not call `getView()` or `getActivity()` before the activity is finished building. Therefore you need to only call these methods afterwards by overiding the `onActivityCreated(...)` method.